# Spying on a method with sinon. Method bound to event listener. Method was executed but .calledOnce is false?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sinon

My code is functioning properly, but my test case is failing for one of its expectations. I don't understand why my spy fails to believe that a method has been executed.

I bind an event listener like so:

```
var playlists = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.on('add', this._onAdd);
    },

    //  Method:
    _onAdd: function (model, collection, options) {
        console.log('onAdd');
        this._foo();
    },

    _foo: function(){
        console.log('foo');
    }
});

Playlists = new playlists();
```

and I am using sinon to spy on my object:

```
it('should call _onAdd when adding a model to the collection', function() {
    sinon.spy(Playlists, '_onAdd');
    sinon.spy(Playlists, '_foo');

    Playlists.add({});
    expect(Playlists._onAdd.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    expect(Playlists._foo.calledOnce).to.equal(true);

    Playlists._onAdd.restore();
    Playlist._foo.restore();
});
```

My test case fails because the expectation for `_onAdd` being called once is not true. However, the expectation for `_foo` being called once *is* true.

I am doing something incorrect with how I am spying on my event listener. Why does sinon not believe `_onAdd` has been called. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is cause be function references. When you create the playlists in the `Playlists` variable it is running `initialize()` on the `playlists` collection which is setting up the event listener with a reference to `this._onAdd`.

When you make a spy it redefines what _onAdd points to, but doesn't update the reference the event listener is using. Consider the following:

```
_onAdd: function(){...} // Call this FuncRefA
```

When `initialize` is called (via `new playlists();`) the event listener will be evaluated to point at `FuncRefA` because this is what `_onAdd` points to at the time of evaluation.

```
this.on('add', FuncRefA);
```

Then when you add the spy, it is effectively doing something like this.

```
_onAdd: function(){ FuncRefA() } // Wraps the existing function, Call the new function FuncRefB
```

At this point `_onAdd` now points to `FuncRefB`, but the event listener is still pointing at `FuncRefA` so when your test runs the event listener is being call (and `FuncRefA`), but your spy is not being called, because the event listener doesn't know about it's existence (it is pointing a `FuncRefA`)

There are a couple of solutions:

1) You can setup the spy on the `prototype` on the `playlists` collection before you create `Playlists`, that way when `Playlists` is created is take the function reference to your spy

```
sinon.spy(playlists.prototype, '_onAdd');
Playlists = new playlists();
//... run tests now.
```

2) Make the event listener have an anonymous function that calls on `_onAdd` so that it is evaluated when the event happens. This will allow you to spy the `Playlists`'s `_onAdd` method because it's reference is evaluated once the `add` event is triggered.

```
initialize: function(){
    var self = this;
    this.on('add', function(){ self._onAdd(arguments) });
},
```

Comment: This seems REALLY odd to me. How does one test a singleton without modifying code to support testing? Both of your solutions make sense and I understand why it is happening, but #2 is bad because it makes the code more convoluted to support spying and #1 is bad because it doesn't convey proper intent for my application. Playlists should only be allowed to be instantiated one time.

Comment: @SeanAnderson: Why is **1** problematic? I'd agree that **2** is a bit odd but why is instrumenting the prototype before instantiation bad? I'd actually say that checking if `_onAdd` is called a strange thing to be bothering with, why not test the behavior rather than the explicit call sequence?

Comment: Well, I can make **1** work with some refactoring, but I lose the ability to enforce Playlists as a singleton through design. Currently, Playlists instantiates itself inside of its scope and then exposes the singleton to the outside world. After refactoring, a parent object will need to instantiate Playlists and expose a single instance of it. I am checking _onAdd because I want to ensure that a method inside _onAdd was not executed based on parameters given to _onAdd, but that _onAdd itself was called. If _onAdd wasn't called then the test case could pass erroneously.